# change view component on ionic page

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm pretty familiar with Angular2 and wanted to start developing an app using ionic2. The thing I don't quite understand conceptually is how to achieve angular2 `<router-outlet>` like behaviour in Ionic.

What I want to do is basically creating a single page, split into two different views, the top one should be able to change the view of the lower part. In Angular2 I would do it the following way:

main.html:

```
<div class="top-part">
    <button id="btn1">
    <button id="btn2">
</div>
<div class="bottom-part">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

with routes set up correctly I can 'exchange' the components within the `<router-outler>` by pressing either one of the buttons.

While researching I found that a lot of people seem to be pretty stoked about the Ionic navigation, though I was unable to find an adequate solution in ionic style to my problem.